# Best resources to gather social media statistics

Tags: dataset

I am looking to gather data on the amount of people following/viewing digital artists' content on social media like youtube, tikotok, instagram etc. I've looked around online but I can only find lists like "10 best youtube artists" etc. which are usefull to get a general idea on how big the top art channels are, but doesn't give a comprehensive picture of how large the total audience of this specific genre of content is.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to estimate this number or tips on what websites to look up for gathering such data?
Thank you!